# Can I iterate widgets inside layouts in python and pysimplegui

Tags: layout, iteration, pysimplegui

I am writing a program with python and using pysimplegui.  In one window I ask the user to make a checklist, which I save as a dictionary.  In another window I want to show that checklist, and save the status of the checks.

So I want to change the window which shows the checklist so it is the same as the checklist the user previously gave me.  Right now I'm doing a simplified version, so I want to control the number of sg.Text by using a variable.  However, I am unable to do this.

I was trying to watch the below youtube video, near 3:10.
(3) PySimpleGUI 2020 Part 10 - Generated Layouts. Writing code to create a layout - YouTube

I tried the below.  Please note, this is the simplified version.  I have removed the checkmarks and other things.  I'm just trying to iterate here.

```
def window_chcklst():               #this is the 
    def make_chcklst(text,key):     #make a function which can be called in the layout
        for x in range (1,10):      #iterate 1 through 9
            text2=text+str(x)       # add the iteration number to the text
        yield ([sg.Text(text2,size=(14,1)), sg.Input(key=key)],)      #show the text     

    layout_chcklst = [                     
            make_chcklst('number ','variable'),     #call the function
        ]
    return sg.Window("Checklist", layout_chcklst, margins=(100,50), modal=True)
```

However, the layout gives 'number 9'.  I was expecting 9 lines, going from 1 to 9.  Is there a way to do this?  I thought yield would give all the loop iterations, not just the last one.

If I change the 'text2' to 'text', then the result is 'number 123456789', for obvious reasons.

Comment: Wrong indentation, the `yield` statement should under your `for` loop,